# Why do I get undefined JS with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, ecmascript-6, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel and in my `bootstrap.js` file I have

```
window.ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js');
```

and then I require the `bootstrap.js` file into `app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

And I use `webpack.mix.js` to compile it

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

If I attempt to access progressbar.js inside of `app.js` it works perfectly.

However, If I attempt to use it outside of `app.js` in script tag **that comes after** `app.js` on my pages, `ProgressBar` is `undefined`.

How can I access `ProgressBar` outside of my `app.js` but keep it imported via `app.js` ?

Example on `index.blade.php`

```
<script src="app.js" defer></script>
<script>
  const progress = new ProgressBar; //undefined...
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you get undefined?  Doesn't seem reproducible to me.  You really shouldn't be relying on `const` implementations in the browser either.

Comment: @Devon Have you tried to reproduce it? Secondly, why shouldn't I use `const` ? Are you saying I should use `let` or `var` instead?

Comment: Yes, it works fine.  `const` and `let` are both es6, es6 features may not be implemented in all browsers.

Comment: @Devon Finally figured it out. I had `defer` on the `<script>` tag and for some reason that stopped it from working. As for `const` and `let` - https://caniuse.com/#search=const https://caniuse.com/#search=let Based off of that, I'm happy to use it

Comment: Missed that, yes, that would cause it because you're asynchronously loading your script so the new ProgressBar line would execute before your app.js has loaded.  I've found many people still on Win 7 using IE, but if you're happy not supporting them, that's up to you.

Comment: @Devon I'll use `var` then. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `defer` on the script tag and for some reason that stopped it from working.

Solution:

```
<script src="app.js" defer></script>
```

change to

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that Webpack hides ProgressBar from you, even if you have `ProgressBar` assigned to the `window`. Because you know, Webpack thinks that the bundle has all the code of your app. Solution? Not to bundle it! Instead use minified version of `ProgressBar` and just load it like in good old times. It is perfectly OK, few nanoseconds better or worse, not noticeable.

Comment: But what if I want to use it inside of `app.js` as well? That would mean I've now loaded 2 instances of `progressbar.js` so I don't think this is a good solution

Comment: I've thinked about it, though. It appears it is the case, unfortunately. Well, then I'd dig webpack docs about sharing data with outside of the bundle (with `window` object). Too bad, I am no Webpack expert (I hate it, frankly). Good news: it should be a very simple task. You only need to find a way to assign somehow the property to `window`.